# Convertions between decimal and base 36

Tags: php, base36

I want to convert numbers in base 36 using PHP. The function `base_convert` is not working because I want to convert large numbers: I don't get my initial number if I convert it again from base 36 to decimal.

I tried some function given on multiple websites, but I never get the same result. Also, these two websites (in Javascript) give the same result:

- http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-36-conversion.html
- http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/decimal-to-base-36/

For example `1010701001118000000000000000` has to be converted to `3IZS0ZE1RQ68W8SSW4`.

Here are the functions I tried (and which don't work):

- http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.base-convert.php#34510
- http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.base-convert.php#106546
- http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/showsource.php?file=converter.php
- http://www.geoffray.be/blog/php/convertir-des-nombres-en-base-62

Comment: why not convert your number to string and then encode with base64?

Comment: The idea is to reduce the length of the number.

Comment: Do you need to convert the number back to decimal at some point?

Comment: Yes I do, the number in base 36 is just here to be exchanged, I need to get it in decimal at the end (whithout knowing the function used to convert in base 36).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two simple functions using an algorithm found on Wikipedia, while using bcmath to get the calculations even for very large numbers right:

```
function fromDecimalToBase($in, $to) {
    $in = (string) $in;
    $out = '';

    for ($i = strlen($in) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $out = base_convert(bcmod($in, $to), 10, $to) . $out;
        $in = bcdiv($in, $to);
    }

    return preg_replace('/^0+/', '', $out);
}

function fromBaseToDecimal($in, $from) {
    $in = (string) $in;
    $out = '';

    for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($in); $i < $l; $i++) {
        $x = base_convert(substr($in, $i, 1), $from, 10);
        $out = bcadd(bcmul($out, $from), $x);
    }

    return preg_replace('/^0+/', '', $out);
}
```

However, I get `3izs0ze1rq66tifrpc` for the number you've provided - maybe your conversion was wrong there?

Comment: You get the same result as the other answer, maybe the Javascript converters are wrong... But I don't know how to find out. I may have to find a "perfect" converter to know...

Comment: @Yoone I've added the conversion back to decimal, and it seems to work so far.

Comment: But, I can use only the first one and just swap `$from` and `$to` :). Whatever, I see that you use the PHP function `base_convert`, so I think your conversion is the right one. I'll accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: The difference between the two functions is mainly, that the first one computes % and / in the source-system while the second one computes + and * in the target-system. Since bcmath can only handle decimal numbers, you will need to use the first one to get from decimal to any other base (so that "decimal" is the source-system) and the second one to get from any base back to decimal ("decimal" = target-system).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/base_conversion/base_conversion.php

This page show you how to convert arbitrary length numbers between different bases.
I tried your example and it looks like it works in both directions. **Source code written in PHP
is available**.

Comment: I don't know which code is right, but with your link, I get `3IZS0ZE1RQ66TIFRPC` instead of `3IZS0ZE1RQ68W8SSW4`