# How to increment alphanumeric string with just lower case letters and numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how to increment an alphanumeric string with only lower case letters (a-z) and numbers (0-9).  I'm trying to check all the possible combinations of the string, which is 64 characters long, so the string would look something like
`g67de5c1e86bc123442db60ae9ce615042dbf4e14e7z481ba3c1c9c3219101gh`
(for those of you thinking it, the string is a seed for the hash function).  The string would need to be incremented from the end to the beginning. Is there a way to increment it?

Comment: By increment by one you mean, transforming last "h" with "i" ?

Comment: this is one of those questions that are more complex to understand that solving

Comment: Please provide some relevant code examples. We love to help you, but we can't see the futher or your screen right now....

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471991/convertions-between-decimal-and-base-36), or at least close enough - convert a large base 36 number to decimal, increment it, then convert it back again.

Answer (score 1):

We define an alphabet "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqstuvxzyz". Assuming that an increment would work from end to the beginning and each increment would "add" one to the ASCII value of the alphabet:

For example:

> "a" will become "b"
>
> "0" will become "1"
>
> "9" will become "a"
>
> "z" will become "0"
>
> "abc" -> "abd"
>
> "01z" -> "020"
>
> ..
>
> etc

The following algorithm will work:

```
<?php


class Increment {
    private $alphabet;

    public function __construct($alphabet)
    {
        $this->alphabet = $alphabet;
    }

    public function getNext($text)
    {
        $length = strlen($text);
        $increment = true;
        for ($i=$length; $i--; $i > 0) {
            $currentCharacter = $text[$i];
            if ($increment) {
                $increment = $this->hasReachEndOfAlphabet($currentCharacter);
                $text[$i] = $this->getIncrementedCharacter($currentCharacter);

            }
        }

        return $text;
    }

    private function getIncrementedCharacter($currentCharacter)
    {
        $position = strpos($this->alphabet, $currentCharacter);
        if (!$this->hasReachEndOfAlphabet($currentCharacter)) {
            return $this->alphabet[++$position];
        }

        return $this->alphabet[0];
    }

    private function hasReachEndOfAlphabet($currentCharacter)
    {
        $position = strpos($this->alphabet, $currentCharacter);
        if ($position < strlen($this->alphabet) -1) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
} //end of class

$text = "g67de5c1e86bc123442db60ae9ce615042dbf4e14e7z481ba3c1c9c3219101gh";
$alphabet = "0123456789";
for ($i=97;$i<=122;$i++) {
    $alphabet .= chr($i);
}
$increment = new Increment($alphabet);
$next = $increment->getNext($text);

print_r($next.PHP_EOL); // outputs g67de5c1e86bc123442db60ae9ce615042dbf4e14e7z481ba3c1c9c3219101gi
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I never even thought of adding my own alphabet and using that!