# Increment Letter Number Combination

Tags: php

I came across this post ([How to increment alphanumeric string with just lower case letters and numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866349/how-to-increment-alphanumeric-string-with-just-lower-case-letters-and-numbers-in)) but my understanding of php is not this advanced.

I want to produce an output for the following combination of letters and numbers:

AA1AA1), incrementing from the right (AA1AA2) etc, then cycling through the letters (AA1AB1), etc all the way to ZZ0ZZ0.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

## UPDATE

I understand that this will output a total of 45 million combinations, but the plan is to create a form to populate ranges. AA1AA1 - AA1AB1 -> SUBMIT. So I was just looking for assistance with the code to do the increment and the rest I will try and figure out.

Thank you!

## RESULTS

```
$field_start = "AA0AA0";
$field_end = "AA0AB2";

for ($value = $field_start; $value <= $field_end; $value++) { 
    echo $value . " <br />";
}
```

Outputs:

AA0AA0
AA0AA1
AA0AA2
AA0AA3
AA0AA4
AA0AA5
AA0AA6
AA0AA7
AA0AA8
AA0AA9
AA0AB0
AA0AB1
AA0AB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the basic increment operator `++` will account for the various overflow and icrementing if a string with characters and numbers.  So something like

```
$start = 'AA1AA1';
while ( $start != 'AA1AD2') {
    echo ($start++)."   ";
}
```

will output

```
AA1AA1   AA1AA2   AA1AA3   AA1AA4   AA1AA5   AA1AA6   AA1AA7   AA1AA8   AA1AA9   AA1AB0   AA1AB1
```

Comment: <?php
for ($x = $firstField; $x <= $secondField; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
}
?>

Comment: It's the same as the `while()` loop, so try it.

Comment: Thank-you @Nigel Ren, I ended up using for(), and have got the basic principals mapped out - now I can learn how to add it to an admin section for wordpress plugin... I've updated the main question with my results.